# jqPlot DateAxisRenderer tickInterval issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am using jqPlot to illustrate some time series data. At the same time, I have a drop-down menu which controls tick interval of the x-axis (time axis). The tick interval can be changed dynamically, but the last tick is always out of range.

For example, my x axis upper bound is `Dec 1 1961`, the starting date is `Jan 2 1961`, and the interval is `3 month`. Then the last tick on the axis is `Jan 2 1962`, not the actual upper bound. So my question is how to make the tick interval only work within the x axis boundary (like to compare to the upper bound before extrapolation). Thanks!

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/godhong/aZwHL/#base) of my plot.

### Try to explain myself a little bit better.

1. The last number on the x axis should be the last element of the
   array x_date2[300]. If the difference between the first date
   x_date[0] and last one can be divided by the value of tick interval,
   then everything is good.
2. If not, except the last element which is the upper bound, the intervals
   between other ticks should be controlled by the drop-down tick interval
   selection.

JS:

```
var x_water = [data are available on JSFIDDLE]
var x_date2 = [data are available on JSFIDDLE]
var x_date2_len = x_date2.length;
var paired = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= x_date2_len; i += 1) {
    paired.push([x_date2[i], x_water[i]]);
}

$('#calc1').click(function (range_interval) {
    var range_interval = $("#display_interval_1").val();
    createplot1(range_interval);
});

function createplot1(range_interval) {
    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    $('#chart1').empty();
    $.jqplot('chart1', [paired], {
        seriesDefaults: {
            showMarker: false,
            pointLabels: {
                show: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            label: 'Water Concentrations'
        }],
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                tickOptions: {
                    formatString: '%#m/%#d/%Y',
                    angle: -30
                },
                min: x_date2[0],
                max: x_date2[300],
                tickInterval: range_interval,
                label: 'Date',
                pad: 0
            },
            yaxis: {
                label: 'Water Total (μg/L)',
                labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                pad: 0
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            location: 'nw',
            placement: 'inside',
            fontSize: '11px'
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function createplot1 I changed the max: x_date2[300] to max: x_date2[200]. I chose this number randomly to see the effect and now it works how you want.

Comment: Could you please provide the code? I tried `tickInterval: <range_interval`, failed

Comment: in the for loop, the second parameter you have i<= x_date2_length, change this to i<x_date2_length.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to jqplot not to plot non-existed x axis values, which was caused by changing tickinterval.

Comment: Right. But I need is not matter what tickinterval I am using. The last number in the x axis should be the last date x_date2[300]. Then except the last number which is the bound, the intervals between other ticks should be controlled by the drop-down tick selection.